# How to programatically create a Custom Binding with TransportWithMessageCredential?

Tags: wcf

I need to programatically create a `wsHttpBinding` (Custom Binding) and for this I need the following configuration:

```
    <binding name="ws_IMembershipService_TransportWithMessageCredential_Username" messageEncoding="Text" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

What is the equivalent to this config in C#?

Comment: Or you can just serialize some random classes to have the same configuration as what you are tring tp achieve

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

EDIT: Still not sure if this will get you what you need, but maybe a good starting point. If not let me know I will delete.

```
   CustomBinding cb = new CustomBinding()
        {   
            SendTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            ReceiveTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            CloseTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            OpenTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),                              
        };
        HttpsTransportBindingElement a = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        a.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10000000;
        a.MaxBufferSize = 524288;
        a.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
        a.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.None;
        SymmetricSecurityBindingElement b = SecurityBindingElement.CreateSspiNegotiationBindingElement(true);
        TextMessageEncodingBindingElement c = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        SecurityBindingElement d = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
        d.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
        c.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas() { MaxDepth = 32, MaxStringContentLength = 8192, MaxArrayLength = 16384, MaxBytesPerRead = 4096, MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384 };            
        cb.CreateBindingElements();
        cb.Elements.Add(a);
        cb.Elements.Add(b);
        cb.Elements.Add(c);
        cb.Elements.Add(d);
```

Comment: There s no `WSHttpBinding` anymore. At least I cannot see it. I use *netcore* and apparently there is a bug when setting `SecurityMode`: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/8

Comment: @DAG ah okay, did not quite understand the question there. I made an update to the answer, not sure how applicable it is for you, if it is far off I will just delete it. good luck.